# Fetch the next value in the column using counter variable and without any array in SQL?

Tags: php, sql, select

I want to move to next row in a column using a variable. Like I have a column `dr`. Now  when I have done calculations to first value of `dr` , I want to go to next value in the column, and perform some calculations there, and then to third and so on.

**Algorithm**

1. Get the value of `$payment`from the user.
2. Select `$dr` from a table `balance`.
3. Calculate `$debited_amount` = `$dr`- `$payment`. There can be three cases.

   > a) `$debited_amount`< 0   // when the user pays more amount as he needs to pay for `gp_no` = 1
   >
   > > b) `$debited_amount` > 0)  // when the user pays less amount as he needs to pay for `gp_no` = 1
   > >
   > > > c) `$debited_amount` = 0 // when the user pays exactly the same amount as he needs to pay for `gp_no` = 1
4. If (c) , then update `balance` by setting `$dr`= 0 for first group and exit;
5. If (b) , then update `balance` by setting `$dr`= `$debited_amount` for first group and exit;
6. If (a) , then update `balance` by setting `$dr`= `0` for first group and select `dr` for next group and goto step3 ;

Below is the PHP code:

```
<?php

 If(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])!='')
{

$member_no = $_REQUEST['member_no'];
$payment = $_REQUEST['payment'];



$sql = "create view balance as select gp_no,sum(dr) as dr from instalment WHERE  member_no = '$member_no' group by gp_no" ;
$sql = "select * from balance";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

     $dr = $row["dr"];

    }
}

$debited_amount = $dr - $payment ; 
$payment = $payment - $dr;


$i = 1 ;
do 
 {

     if ($debited_amount < 0 )   // when the user pays more amount as he needs to pay for gp_no = 1
     {
          $sql = "update balance set dr = 0 WHERE  gp_no = '$i' " ;// dr will be updated by dr = 0;
           $dr++; // and move to next dr for subratraction i.e., dr of gp_no = 2 
          $i++;
          $debited_amount = $dr - $payment ;        
          $payment = $payment - $debited_amount ;       
     }
     elseif ($debited_amount > 0)  // when the user pays less amount as he needs to pay for gp_no = 1
     {
         $sql = "update balance set dr = $debited_amount WHERE  gp_no = '$i' " ;// dr will be updated by dr = $debited_amount ; 
         $dr = $debited_amount ; 
         $payment = $payment + $debited_amount ;
     }
     else  // when the user pays exactly the same amount as he needs to pay for gp_no = 1
     {
         $sql = "update balance set dr = 0 WHERE  gp_no = '$i' " ;// dr will be updated by dr = 0;
         $dr = 0;
     }


} while ($payment !=0 );
```

Comment: `plz tell me code for this` - people will assist you here, but they won't do it for you. What is the code you wish to use to select values of `dr`? I expect you'll need a `SELECT` query for this.  Perhaps you should add that first? If you just wish to use the view you have created, perhaps you should just use the select statement on its own - creating a view does not return rows.

Comment: Also, your view creation statement is vulnerable to SQL Injection - don't put this live yet.

Comment: @halfer : Since I'm new to this , that's why did those mistakes. 
Edited the code though .
And about SQL Injection , I've reserved that feature of security for the pro version of this S/W . Its just a beta version .
Now , coming to the query , I want to move onto the next value in the column .

Comment: Your new code will not work, as the view will not be created, since the SQL variable will be overwritten before it is executed. Of course, if the view already exists, it will run. You have correctly added a `while()` loop, but I am not sure what you want it to do - presently you are just reading a column value.

Comment: Maybe you need to explain your full, intended algorithm, in your question?

Comment: @halfer Replaced view with table .

Comment: So what problem is it that you are trying to solve? It is still not clear. For example, "I want to allow a number of users to make partial or full payments against a loan" or whatever. What does `$dr` represent?

Comment: @halfer : I'm unable to implement the 6th step. I want to fetch the value of  a column `dr` one by one in some variable or probably in any array ? I don't know how to do that .
`$dr` is the `debit` that gets add up in every members' account when any bid is placed . So, when the member pays(`$payment`), his outstanding debit(`$dr`) should get modified .

Comment: Again, what problem is it that you are trying to solve? It is still not clear. For example, "I want to maintain a list of bids in an auction system, maintaining a balance for each member that can be debited and credited". Can we see the table structure of the tables in this system? You have `instalment` and `balance`, what do they look like? Please add a full column breakdown in your question.